# How to call script which is having menus, from another script

Tags: shell-script

I have a script called operation.sh and while i am running the script, will be getting output like below and will wait for user input.

```
 1. Start
 2. Restart
 3. Stop
 4. Status
 Enter Option:
```

Once I pressed "1", it will perform some logic and again it will come to above view.

I need to call the operation.sh from other sh (i.e., other.sh) like,

```
 sh other.sh
```

It has to perform the same logic as when I pressed 1 in operation.sh.

other.sh is having below content.

```
sh operation.sh 1
```

I could understand, it doesn't make sense (but I tried since I don't have any idea).

How can I call a menu script(which is performing action based on user selected menu) from another script.

Comment: Look at `expect`.

Comment: @Henrik, i have't tried with expect. and I have idea. But, Is there any other way without using expect.?

Comment: Related: [Prepare answers for questions of a command](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204683/prepare-answers-for-questions-of-a-command)

Comment: depends on how the other script reads its input.  for instance, for some ways that use standard input, `echo 1 | sh other.sh` might work

Answer (score 0):

```sh
#!/bin/sh 

OPC1() {
echo "Opcion 1"
}

OPC2() {
echo "Opcion 2"
}

SELECCIONA() {
if ( test $opc -eq 1 )
then
     OPC1
else
     OPC2
fi
}

#### MAIN ##########

opc=$1

if [ $1 ]
then
    SELECCIONA
else
    echo "1. start "
    echo "2. stop "
    echo "0. salir "
    read opc
    SELECCIONA
fi
```

Comment: i can't modify target script. can't i achieve my scenario without modifying target script?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `echo -e "1\n2"` piped to the script.  Just put the menu responses separated by newlines (`\n`) in the string after `-e`.

```
echo -e "1\n2" | operation.sh
```

Another option is to put the responses in order one per line in a text file.  You can then cat that file and pipe it to the script.

```
cat responses.txt | operation.sh
```