# Making a script interact with another program

Tags: shell-script

Let's say I have this program `math` that generates and prints a random math question and than waits for an input.

How would I create a script to receive the input, process it, and then print it back to the original program?

I've tried to do something like this
`./math | script.sh | ./math`
but the second program generates a different problem, so it doesn't work.

Comment: Possibly related: [Prepare answers for questions of a command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204683/prepare-answers-for-questions-of-a-command)

Comment: The program generates a random problem each time, so I don't know the answers beforehand.

Comment: Without testing (I don't have such programs able to chat with each other), I would give a try to: `./math <&3 | script.sh >&3`, or with named pipes: `mkfifo fifo ; (./math <fifo | script.sh >fifo)`. See [Bash One-Liners Explained, Part III: All about redirections](https://catonmat.net/bash-one-liners-explained-part-three) for instance.

Answer (score 3):

Without any sample output or behavior, it's hard to provide an exact response, but it seems you're looking for the `expect` command.

Manpage [expect(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect):

```
EXPECT(1)                   General Commands Manual                  EXPECT(1)



NAME
       expect - programmed dialogue with interactive programs, Version 5

SYNOPSIS
       expect [ -dDinN ] [ -c cmds ] [ [ -[f|b] ] cmdfile ] [ args ]

INTRODUCTION
       Expect  is a program that "talks" to other interactive programs accord‐
       ing to a script.  Following  the  script,  Expect  knows  what  can  be
       expected  from  a  program and what the correct response should be.  An
       interpreted language provides branching and high-level  control  struc‐
       tures  to  direct the dialogue.  In addition, the user can take control
       and interact directly when desired, afterward returning control to  the
       script.
```