# Implement batch option --yes in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have several user input statements like:

```
read -r -p "Do u want to include this step (y) or not (n) (y/N)"? answer
if [[ "$answer" =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then 
    ...
fi
```

I am looking for a way to automatically answering yes to all these questions. Imagine a non-interactive session where the user invokes the script with `--yes` option. No further `stdin` input.

The only way I can think right now is adding another condition on **each** if statement.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prepare answers for questions of a command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204683/prepare-answers-for-questions-of-a-command)

Comment: `[[ "$1" = "--yes" ]] && command || read -r -p "Do u want...`, something like this will work for you? I ask taking in accout your response to Jesse_b answer.

Comment: @guillermochamorro Thanks, this works, but I would have to change any statement :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use `read` only for these questions, and the variable is always called `answer`, replace `read`:

```bsh
# parse options, set "$yes" to y if --yes is supplied
if [[ $yes = y ]]
then
    read () {
        answer=y
    }
fi
```

Comment: That's neat, and possibly confusing for a reader who doesn't know the script. I would suggest at least renaming the function to alleviate that (and to allow using `read` in the ordinary sense elsewhere in the script, if required).

Comment: @ilkkachu ah, but that way,  OP will have to go about modifying the usages of `read`, which is something they're looking to avoid. To avoid confusion, maybe logging that the read is being overridden is better. And they can always use `builtin read` for the ordinary sense.

Comment: @muru, sure, but changing the function name is a rather minor modification anyway. It could possibly even be automated with something like `sed -e '/read.*answer/s/read/read_or_yes/'`

Answer (score 10):

You could use [yes(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/yes.1.html), which shouldn't require any modification to your script at all.

```
$ grep . test.sh
#!/bin/bash
read -rp 'What say you? ' answer
echo "Answer is: $answer"
read -rp 'And again? ' answer2
echo "Answer 2 is: $answer2"
$
$ yes | ./test.sh
Answer is: y
Answer 2 is: y
```

It will repeat a specified expletive indefinitely, if none is specified it will default `y`.

Comment: Thank you. Good thought, however, optimally, I would prefer to not change the way the script is been called already: `./test.sh --yes` - On the other hand I could use it as a work-around :)

Comment: I guess the "trick" version of this one would be to parse options as per the accepted answer, then conditionally `exec 0< <(yes)` (possibly duplicating the descriptor first so that it can be restored if stdin is needed again later). But it's hacky compared to overloading `read`.

Comment: Upside of piping input from `yes`: it'll automatically answer "yes" to any commands launched by the shell, too (e.g. `cp -i`). Downside of using `yes`: it'll automatically answer "yes" to any commands launched by the shell, too. ;)

Comment: Uh, any reason you didnt cat your sample script? Surprised to see a grep there

Comment: Quick and dirty empty line removal? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: cat is intended to concatenate files, not read them.

Comment: @jesse_b and grep is for searching... from ex/vi: globally search re and p(rint). If you want to be that pedantic, you could use `printf '%s\n' %p q | ed file` to read the file... again, just questioning why that complex approach when a simple one will do. I’m all for eliminating useless use of cats, but this ain’t one in my book

Answer (score 6):

I would put the whole decision logic in a function, both checking the auto-mode and possibly querying the user. Then call just that from the main level in each case. `want_act` below returns truthy/falsy in itself, no need for a string comparison in the main level and it's clear to the reader what the condition does.

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ $1 = --yes ]] && yes_mode=1

want_act() {
    [[ $yes_mode = 1 ]] && return 0
    read -r -p "Include step '$1' (y/n)? " answer
    [[ $answer = [Yy]* ]] && return 0
    return 1
}

if want_act "frobnicate first farthing"; then
    echo "frobnicating..."
fi
```

Comment: From a maintenance perspective this is a better option than overriding `read`. On the other hand, if that option hadn't already been offered i would have suggested it myself. +1 to you both, I think.

Comment: Suggestion: like I did, switch the implementation itself based on the option: `if [[ $yes_mode = 1 ]]; then want_act() { ...;}; else want_act() { ...;}; fi`. The check for the option only needs to be done once, after all.

Comment: Nice one, thanks!